# How can I use Let's Encrypt to generate a certificate to be used for a WCF rest service?

Tags: wcf, rest, amazon-web-services, ssl

I've been researching heavily on this topic, and I really hope that someone out there has already done this.

I'm building a mobile app for iOS and Android using Xamarin.Forms. The app accesses a rest service, and I need to use SSL encryption to protect the data of my users.

My rest service is running on a Windows Server 2012 Amazon ec2 instance. I'm building the rest service using WCF. I'm not using IIS to host this service. It runs on a port, let's say 29640. So, the client is calling my port with the request and the parameters.

I tried to use Let's Encrypt to generate an SSL certificate for my server, but Amazon aws server's are blacklisted from getting an SSL certificate. I do have an SSL certificate for the domain of my website which is hosted on a GoDaddy Linux server. Sadly, that is not where my WCF requests are hosted.

I'm just so confused. How do I get an SSL certificate that my clients can trust. Is the only option to route requests through my known domain instead of through EC2? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using Elastic IP and DNS records for a domain that I own. I know that elastic IP sounds like it will change, but it means that any new instance you start can be assigned that same IP address.

1. Set up an elastic IP for your instance so that your DNS record will stay current. You get 1 free elastic IP per Amazon EC2 instance.
2. Set up a CName for your record. I am using GoDaddy, but you can set up a CName in any DNS manager. I used a new subdomain of format "subdomain.abc.com" and pointed it to the elastic IP address.
3. I needed to open up port 80 and 443 in my EC2 security group.
4. Using IIS on your server (you may need to install it and create your site), go to the bindings for your site. Associate port 80 and port 443 with your "subdomain.abc.com" host name. You'll need to wait until the DNS setting has propagated. Ping your "subdomain.abc.com" in your browser until the site hosted with your IIS (mine was the default site) responds.
5. I used the awesome [win simple lets encrypt tool](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple). It will automatically find your IIS domain and generate the SSL certificate. If it doesn't work, make sure you're able to hit that new DNS record you made in your browser.